# Finding and locally deleting deleted records in a million-record table

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017, subquery

I'm trying to incrementally load data from a remote server to a local one (using SSIS and linked server). Remote table has 1.7 million of records, increasing every hour. So far, I have been able to load new records and update existing records using their RECID and LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME fields. But when I try to find records which are deleted since last refresh, I face a never-ending operation:

`DELETE FROM localdb.dbo.INVENTTRANS WHERE RECID NOT IN (SELECT RECID FROM REMOTESERVER.remotedb.dbo.INVENTTRANS)`

I tried running `SELECT RECID FROM REMOTESERVER.remotedb.dbo.INVENTTRANS` and it loads data in less than 10 seconds, hence there is no network/performance issue. But when I run the above DELETE query, it doesn't finish even after 15 minutes. I tried copying RECIDs to a local table to prevent possible reciprocations between local and remote server, no luck. Can someone guide me to improve performance of such a query?

Comment: Queries across servers are much slower than local ones. Pull the current RECID data into a local staging or temporary table then separately act on it. Carefully sequence or add conditions to things so there is no chance a very new record gets deleted in error.

Comment: Yea so the issue here is likely the Linked Server. Is this database for Microsoft's Dynamics Axapta ERP system by any chance? If so, if I recall correctly, RecID is the primary key and / or clustered index? If so, then re-writing your query in a more relational way may prevent you from getting a Remote Scan operation and instead result in a more performant Remote Query operation.

Comment: @Brian as I have written in my post, I tried copying all RECIDs to a local table, but his didn't change anything. The problem is number of records, not cross-server query.

Comment: @J.D. as I replied to Brian, even copying data locally doesn't change anything. My data source is Microsoft Dynamics 365 F&O (AKA AX 365). I'm trying to find a rational way for re-writing this query, but I already know that I should prevent remove scanning, hence tested copying data to local table. This should prevent any problem rising from PK/clustered index status as my destination table neither has PK not index (because I don't need such things).

Comment: You copied all the data locally and ran your query with no Linked Server involved and it's still slow? Or you only brought the `RECID`s over locally but still executed the query against the Linked Server?

Answer (score 0):

try this merge statement...

```
with trg as (
select RECID, LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME, column1,column2 FROM targettable
),
src as (
select * from openquery(linked_server_name,'select * from soucetable')
)
MERGE trg AS TARGET
USING src AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.RECID = SOURCE.RECID
WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE.LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME > TARGET.LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME
   THEN UPDATE
       set TARGET.LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME = SOURCE.LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME
       TARGET.column1 = SOURCE.column1
       TARGET.column2 = SOURCE.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
   THEN INSERT
     (RECID, LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME, column1, column2) VALUES (SOURCE.RECID, SOURCE.LASTMODIFIEDDATEANDTIME, SOURCE.column1, SOURCE.column2) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
   THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, 
DELETED.RECID AS DeletedTargetRECID, 
INSERTED.RECID AS INSERTEDRECID
;
```